# John the Ripper not fully using CPU

Tags: macos, passwords, zip, cpu-usage, hashing

I'm using John the Ripper to crack an old ZIP archive encrypted with PKZIP, and although I've set the thread count to match the number of cores I have (4) only about 50-60% of my CPUs are being used for hashing.

To be clear though, *all* of the CPU cores are being used but only at 50-60% according to htop. Activity Monitor reports CPU usage as ~45% idle and the `john` process as using ~210% CPU usage (rather than the expected almost-400%).

The relevant specs are:

- 4-core i5-7600k overclocked to 4.8GHz
- macOS 10.13.4 (hackintosh)
- Compiled John the Ripper from: https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper (commit 7adcb8c)
- No similar problems from other software, or other instability to speak of. prime95, for example, has no problem maxing out all cores

Comment: What kind of attack are you using? Straight wordlist, or masks, or something else?

Comment: @RoyceWilliams I'm using all default options right now (`./john list.txt`)